# Pygame - Recolor pixes of a certain color to another using SurfArray (Array slicing issue)

Tags: python, arrays, colors, pygame, slice

I'm trying to make a palette swap functionality for a game, and I'm trying to find a way to change the color of pixels of a certain color to another. I've been able to make all of the pixels the same color with this function I found in a tutorial:

```
def color_surface(self,surface, red, green, blue):
    arr = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)
    arr[:,:,0] = red
    arr[:,:,1] = green
    arr[:,:,2] = blue
```

As far as I can tell, the first two indices are the location of the pixel, and the third is the color channel, right? Thinking that, I came up with this function here:

```
def recolor(self,fromColor,toColor):
    arr = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(self.image)
    for color in arr[:,:,0:]:
        if color == fromColor:
            color = toColor
```

Now, I'm absolutely certain I'm messing up the array slicing. What I'm trying to do is to get a list of all of the pixels as a length 3 array of colors, and if that array matches fromColor, it switches to toColor. It's not working, though, and its wicked slow in not working. Is there an easier way?

Or am I just misunderstanding the surfArray entirely and the indexes are not what I'm thinking they are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something less general, but there is a [replace](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray.replace) method in the `PixelArray` module used for replacing one color with another.

```
arr = PixelArray(surface)
arr.replace(fromColor, toColor)
del arr
```

That would change one color on a surface to another.  The `del` statement is there because otherwise the surface remains locked for as long as the `PixelArray` object exists.

As for the array slicing, a [section in the NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) explains the syntax.

Comment: Well. I did not know that was a thing.

Thank you for that!

Comment: As an update to this, if you're using 1.9.4, you may wish to use `arr.close()` instead of deleting the PixelArray object outright. [Details in the doc here.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray.close)